# dynamically change bitmap in imageView, android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bitmap

All,

I have a problem related to imageView, android.
  I have array which contains of 10 bitmap objects, called `bm`.
  I have a imageView, called `im`.

Now I wanna show the bitmaps in the array in im one by one, so I did the following:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
             im.setImageBitmap(bm[j]);
         }
       }
      }).start();
```

But the result only shows the last bitmap in the array.

Can someone tell me what to do with this issue?

Millions of thanks!

Comment: btw, this chunk of code is in onCreate() method of an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't ever change a UI element in a thread.  Most of the time this results in an exception.  I don't know why it didn't here.
2. You're blasting through all ten images in a mere milliseconds.  That's why the last one is the only one you see.  You need to slow it down.
3. The easiest way would be the Handler/Runnable implementation like so:

   ```
   im.post(new Runnable() {   
      int j = 0;      
      @Override   
      public void run() {
         im.setImageBitmap(bm[j]);
         if(j++ < 10){
            im.postDelayed(this, 1000);
         }
      }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you sir, you just said never change a UI element in a thread, so what is the best way to do so?

Comment: This runs on the UI thread, so this is a way you can do it.  Dmytro's answer is another way.

Answer (score 1):

You need insert a `sleep` call after setting a new image so that your eyes will have the chance to see the images :). Something like:

```
im.setImageBitmap(bm[j]);
try {                             
    Thread.sleep(5000);           
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();          
}
```

Should keep the image for five seconds before advancing to the next one.

Like others have suggested, you will need use `postDelayed` to properly notify the UI that you are setting a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should have exception, as you can work with view's only in UI Thread.
   You should call [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method on your view if you want to make changes with it.
2. Actually it is changed so fast that you see only last item.

Here is correct code:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                final int index = j;
                im.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        im.setImageBitmap(bm[index]);
                    }
                }, j * 1000); // delay j seconds
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: I still think creating a thread like this would be overkill.  It's got to run on the UI no matter what.

Comment: Method "postDelayed" is called on UI Thread, am I missing something?

Comment: It is, but you're also creating a thread to cycle a loop of 10 times to call methods on the UI thread. It would work, but it just seems redundant.

Comment: thank you, I just tried your code, but eclipse says that "Cannot refer to a non-final variable j inside an inner class defined in a different method"